# Calling external APIs from angular 2 in .NET Core app returns 404

Tags: api, angular, asp.net-core, angular-cli

I setup .Net Core project following [this tutorial](http://www.sparkhound.com/learn/blog/setting-up-an-asp-net-core-project-with-angular-2-utilizing-angular-cli). I added angular cli into the project, built it through command "ng build --prod". The angular app is served as static files from wwwroot folder in the .Net Core app.

I also setup proxy.config server to serve other APIs. When I start command "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json" the app starts and calling the other APIs within the app works fine. The issue is when I start .Net Core app as command "dotnet run", the angular app loads and runs fine, but calling APIs returns 404. Do you know why it is? Do I miss anything?

Comment: Are you able to hit an API endpoint just using the browser (by going to a GET endpoint by entering it in as the URL) or with a tool like Postman?

Comment: Yes, each API call works fine from Postman. I found that if I want to call API from the Angular app the webAPI must be on the same domain as it's Angular app. I had to add full path to API in the Angular http services in the production build.

Comment: That would make sense. If you have them hosted together, you can use relative paths to access the API, but if you want the API hosted in a different location, you would have to specify the absolute path in the project and may also have to enabled CORS.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation ;)